# Xamarin iOS images overlapping inside Grid

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Heyo,

So in Xamarin I have a `<Grid>` with an `<Image>` and a couple `<Label>`s inside it, all wrapped inside a `<ViewCell>`. This looks totally fine in Xamarin.Android, however in Xamarin.iOS the images overlap the labels. I'm not sure what the difference could be - why does it look good in Xamarin.Android but in iOS its all wonky?

Below is my XAML and a couple mockups to show what I mean.

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <ViewCell.View>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding ImageOverlayEN}" />
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" Text="{Binding DynamicOfferText}" FontSize="18">
                    <Label.FontFamily>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                        <OnPlatform.iOS>RobotoCondensed-Regular</OnPlatform.iOS>
                        <OnPlatform.Android>RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf#RobotoCondensed-Regular</OnPlatform.Android>
                        <OnPlatform.WinPhone>RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf#RobotoCondensed</OnPlatform.WinPhone>
                    </OnPlatform>
                    </Label.FontFamily>
                </Label>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" Text="{Binding DynamicOfferDetail}" FontSize="16">
                    <Label.FontFamily>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                        <OnPlatform.iOS>RobotoCondensed-Regular</OnPlatform.iOS>
                        <OnPlatform.Android>RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf#RobotoCondensed-Regular</OnPlatform.Android>
                        <OnPlatform.WinPhone>RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf#RobotoCondensed</OnPlatform.WinPhone>
                    </OnPlatform>
                    </Label.FontFamily>
                </Label>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell.View>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

I tried setting the `HeightRequest` but that didn't seem to make a difference:

```
#if __IOS__
    if (viewModel.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        MyListView.HeightRequest = 300 * viewModel.Items.Count;
    }
#endif
```

Here is a visual representation of what is happening:

[image]

Comment: In your Row definitions, it looks there's only two defined but you're trying to put the last label in row 2, which doesn't exist. Try adding another row definition.

Comment: Nope, same issue. I had read somewhere that the row definitions are only if you want to change the default behavior of rows, you don't actually need to include them. Either way though it didn't make a difference :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out - had to do with my `RowDefinitions` being all set to `Auto`

This got it looking just right:

```
<RowDefinition Height="1*" />
<RowDefinition Height="0.18*" />
<RowDefinition Height="0.77*" />
```

I think what was happening is the `ListView` renders first, the `Auto` row definition heights set the height of each row **before** the image is done loading, then the image finishes loading and overlaps the rest of the list view's item (including the labels). This might just be a quirk of iOS, where as Android calculates the row heights after the images are done loading (explaining why it looked fine in Android)

Comment: Was just building something like that as an answer...so you get an extra upvote from me ;-)